# Laravel 5.4 Authenticate A User Instance not working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I need authenticate a user from my controller.

```
public function index()
{
    $user = User::find(1);
    Auth::login($user, true);
    dd(Auth::check()); // returns true
}

public function dev()
{
    dd(Auth::check()); // returns  false
}
```

When I run index() that's ok. Script returns **true**. But next when I go to dev() - scripts returns **false**.

I tried with diferrent session drivers (file, cookie, database).

Comment: you are missing these lines in dev() function `$user = User::find(1); ` `Auth::login($user, true);`

Comment: i recommend to  you make constructor for these lines..

Comment: @BilalAhmed I thought framework creates global session for everyone   class by login() method

Comment: what happen when you call `dev` method from `index` like `$this->dev()`  after `Auth::login` ?

Comment: @Niklesh returns true

Comment: So, I think you should also share the info regarding how you are calling `dev` method which is not working

Comment: there are 3 file in laravel route folder from which file you are calling your controller methods ? I think its `api.php` not `web.php` ?

Comment: @Nikesh 
`
Route::get('/', 'AController@index');
Route::get('/a', 'AController@dev');
`
first I go to / in browser and next go to /a

Comment: @Nikesh I stored rules in web.php, is it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

CORRECT CODE:

```
public function index()
{

    $user = User::where('email', 'emailX@gmail.com')->first();
    Auth::login($user, true);

    return view('main');
}

public function dev()
{
    var_dump(Auth::user());
}
```

dd() in the index action is breaks Auth